# sum of debit on the base of month in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table name receipt the scema is as follow

```
account_no  date        transaction_type  amount
   s1       2012-7-7    opening           500
   s1       2012-8-13   deposit           1000
   s1       2012-7-17   deposit           400
```

Now I have the following query

```
select  month(r.date),
  sum(case when (month(r.date))='7' and r.transaction_type='opening' and r.transaction_type='deposit' then r.amount else '' end )as debit 
from receipt r 
where r.account_no='s1'
```

But it is giving me output as:

```
month  debit 
7      0
```

can any one tell me why it is giving me this output ?

**Edit**

if i want to place the name of month instead of number then how to do that

Comment: contradictory condition "r.transaction_type='opening' and r.transaction_type='deposit' "

Comment: If you want *[Add up all the 'opening' values AND all the 'deposit' values]* then you want to rephrase it as *[Add up all values that are 'opening' OR 'deposit']*...  `CASE WHEN month(r.date)=7 AND (r.transaction_type='opening' OR r.transaction_type='deposit') THEN r.amount ELSE 0 END`.  *(Note the `ELSE 0` and not `ELSE ''` as you should not be summing strings, you sum numbers...)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want an `OR` condition between `r.transaction_type='opening' and r.transaction_type='deposit'` instead of the `AND`

```
select date_format(r.date, '%M'),
  sum(case when (month(r.date))='7' 
        and (r.transaction_type='opening' 
          or r.transaction_type='deposit') 
      then r.amount else 0 end )as debit 
from receipt r 
where r.account_no='s1'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c2a/6)

Or you can use:

```
select date_format(r.date, '%M'),
  sum(r.amount)
from receipt r
where r.account_no='s1'
  and month(r.date) = 7
  and r.transaction_type in ('opening', 'deposit')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c2a/8)

If you want to get the `sum()` for all months, then you will need to add a `group by`:

```
select date_format(r.date, '%M'),
  sum(r.amount)
from receipt r
where r.account_no='s1'
  and r.transaction_type in ('opening', 'deposit')
group by month(r.date);
```

OR

```
select date_format(r.date, '%M'),
  sum(case when (r.transaction_type='opening' 
        or r.transaction_type='deposit') 
      then r.amount else 0 end )as debit 
from receipt r 
where r.account_no='s1'
group by month(r.date)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c2a/11)

Comment: @Ashishsingh I have edited my answer to show how you will get the Month Name not number

Comment: if i want to get for all month then how to go ...can you help me on this ?

Comment: @Ashishsingh please see my edit, you will need to remove the condition where `month(r.date) = 7` and then add a `group by month(r.date)`, you should then see the results for each month

Answer (score 2):

You're saying

```
 ...r.transaction_type='opening' and r.transaction_type='deposit'
```

`r.transactiontype` is never going to be **both** 'opening' and 'deposit'

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your query to

```
select month(r.date) as month,
       sum(r.amount) as debit
from receipt r
where r.account_no = 's1'
      and month(r.date) = 7
      and (r.transaction_type = 'opening' or r.transaction_type = 'deposit');
```

changing the `and` to `or` as others already pointed out.